# How to find the date when an email in outbox was effectively sent?

Tags: email, email-client

In various email clients, when an email is put in the outbox to be sent later, the mail is timestamped with the date when it was put there. The delivery time may differ much but is not directly visible. I would like to know how the sender can know the date when the email was effectively sent.

I imagine that it varies depending on the client, but I am most interested in eM Client for Windows. Knowing this for Thunderbird or Outlook would be good too.

On eM client, I explored the interface but did not find it. Then I took a look at the log files but did not find it either.

Comment: Are sent email copied to 'Sent' folder?  YES=> Have you inspected the headers?

Comment: AnFi: Yes. The copy of the email in the Sent folder is just that: a copy of the sent email, not of the augmented email with information from the servers involved in the delivery.